# Bitwise operations: Need to create a large integer, but can only declare an 8bit integer

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I need to create a large integer: (1431655765), which is 01010101, for 4 bytes overall. However, there is the restriction that I'm only allowed to declare a number between 0 to 255. I've thought about declaring 01010101 and then pushing it using << to the left, and then trying to add more of the 01s along the way. However,  this would only get the first byte to be the way I want it, and not the remaining 3 bytes, and I'm not sure how to change the values of the 0's in the other bytes. I also thought about using two's complement, somehow doing some kind of negative, using ~x+1 or something similar. I wasn't sure how to get there from just a one byte integer though. I'm pretty stuck and some help would be appreciated! For context, this is for bitwise operations, I can use, ! ~ & ^ | + << >>

Comment: 'Num32Bit = (Num8Bit << 0) | (Num8Bit << 8) | (Num8Bit << 16) | (Num8Bit << 24)`?

Comment: `01010101` is an easy `0x55` or decimal `85`, so you have that part too.

Comment: *I've thought about declaring 01010101 and then pushing it using << to the left.* That sounds like a great idea.  I'd pursue it.  I don't see why it wouldn't work (as long as you use a type that's big enough, so the `<<` won't overflow).

Comment: For extra credit, try 6148914691236517205. (For *extra* extra credit, try 98382635059784275285.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have numbers a, b, c, d of 8 bits each, and they should form 32-bit number n = abcd let's say, you can do:

```
n = a;
n = (n << 8) | b;
n = (n << 8) | c;
n = (n << 8) | d;
```